# How to erase characters in a string?

Tags: c++, string, erase

I've got problem with erase function from string. I can't remove a single character from certain index. 
Maybe I can't use int "i" as iterator ? I want to remove some characters.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void deleteChars(string inputText, string inputChars);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string tekst1 = ("mama fama lilo babo sabo");
    string tekst2 = ("mabo");

    deleteChars(tekst1, tekst2);

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void deleteChars(string inputText, string inputChars){
          int a = inputText.size();
          int b = inputChars.size();

          string tmp = inputText;

          for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
                  for(int j=0; j<b; j++){
                          if(inputText.at(i)==inputChars.at(j)){
                              tmp.erase(i,1);  //Here is my problem ?
                           }                                    
                  }
          }

          inputText = tmp;

          cout<<"text: "<<inputText<<endl;

}
```

My error:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way
```

Comment: What's tmp? inputText? inputChars? Give sample input, show declarations, etc etc.

Comment: Please provide a **short**, **complete** program that demonstrates the error. Please say what you expect the output of that program to be, and what it actually is. See http://sscce.org for more details.

Comment: Your problem is not in the code you've posted. It's somewhere else in your program. The error you're getting shows that the program is ending in an abnormal way. Please post the whole program if you can.

Comment: Are you reading your answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the beginning, the size of `tmp` is equal to the size of `inputText` which is `a`.

But as soon as you erase a character from `tmp`, its size decreases by one, and becomes `a-1`, and if you erase second time, its size would become `a-2` and so on. So it is possible that at some point, you will pass an index greater than or equal to the size of `tmp`, to the `erase` function, which results in `std::out_of_range` exception which you don't handle and so your application crashes.

Comment: Are you sure it's *undefined behaviour* ? According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/ , it just throws an exception in that case, which simply isn't caught here.

Comment: @DCoder: No, I wasn't sure. I just thought so. But now I realized that it throws `std::out_of_range` exception instead. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 12):

After you erase a character from, say, position 5, what was at position 6 shifts to position 5, and the string length is reduced by one. If you later try to erase the last character of `tmp`, it will throw an exception because `tmp` is already one character shorter than you expect it to be. Iterate over the string *backwards* to avoid this.